# Slug function isnt working

Tags: php

```
function createSlug($slug){

    $lettersNumbersSpacesHyphens = '/[^\-\s\pN\pL]+/u'; 
    $slug = preg_replace($lettersNumbersSpacesHyphens,'',mb_strtolower($slug, 'UTF-8'));
    $slug = preg_replace($spacesDuplicateHyphens,'-',$slug);
    $slug = trim($slug, '-');

    return $slug;
}

$slug       = createSlug($_POST['label']);
```

When i remove the function createSlug from the $_POST['label'], the slug is being added to the database just as the string is. But i'm getting no return value.

Comment: Define `$spacesDuplicateHyphens` in your function.

Answer (score -1):

Insert this line `error_reporting(E_ALL );`, before you call the createSlug(). And after you can see several problems about your code.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment.